# Opencv print a message after face is detected only once

Tags: python, opencv

Currently, I have an opencv face detection script running on my raspberry pi. It is coded in python. The face detection part is working. Basically, I want to send a mqtt message to another raspberry pi once the face is detected. I can easily do this just by publishing to that host, the problem is if the person's face is detected for a long time, multiple messages get sent. Is there a way to send only one message until the face is no longer detected? So basically, the person's face would be detected and one mqtt message would be sent, then no more messages would be sent until the face is not detected. It seems like a pretty simple problem so maybe I am just missing the obvious. Below I have my code that runs the opencv script:

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

host = '10.0.0.192'
client = mqtt.Client("Security")
client.connect(host)

import time
import cv2

threshold = 60  #  BINARY threshold
blurValue = 41  # GaussianBlur parameter
bgSubThreshold = 50
# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 64
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/opencv-face-sentdex/faces.xml')
    # show the frame
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (blurValue, blurValue), 0)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(blur, 1.1, 5)
    if faces is not None:
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),2)
            client.publish("/home/pi/snips-app","faceDetected")#publish

    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Comment: I'm going under the same problem and I can't find a way to solve it. Did anybody ever succeed on this?

Comment: @blackjack I solved this pretty easily. Basically I had a function that checked the last time since the face was captured and the time now and compare the 2. If it was greater than a certain threshold then I printed the face else I didn’t print it. There’s a tutorial on hackerhouse I found useful

Comment: Thank you. I'll look for the tutorial you've mentioned

Comment: @NickD anyone have a link to the tutorial mentioned?

Comment: @JoeyM https://www.hackster.io/hackershack/smart-security-camera-90d7bd